# Wrong numbering with css counters

Tags: html, css

Why the following css doesn't get correct numbering of sections (http://jsfiddle.net/75MHS/)? When I put `h3` and `h4` inside `div`s, all chapter numbers and section numbers are always one. But when I remove `div` containers, the numbers are all correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
h3 {
  counter-increment: chapter;
  counter-reset: section;
}
h3:before {
  content: "Chapter " counter(chapter) " ";
}
h4 {
  counter-increment: section;
}
h4:before {
  content: counter(section) " ";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- wrong counter -->
<div><h3>dddd</h3></div>
<div><h4>dddd</h4></div>
<div><h4>dddd</h4></div>
<div><h3>dddd</h3></div>
<div><h4>dddd</h4></div>
<div><h4>dddd</h4></div>

<!-- correct counter -->
<!--
<h3>dddd</h3>
<h4>dddd</h4>
<h4>dddd</h4>
<h3>dddd</h3>
<h4>dddd</h4>
<h4>dddd</h4>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it works as intended in the second section (without the div's) but doesn't in the fist section is due to counter scope. According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#scope):

> The scope of a counter starts at the first element in the document that has a 'counter-reset' for that counter and includes the element's descendants and its following siblings with their descendants.

In the second half of the html, the `h3`s and `h4`s are siblings, therefore, the `counter-reset` defined on the `h3` applies to the following `h4` siblings. In the first part of the html, the `h4`s are not descendants nor siblings of the `h3`s, therefore, the counter-rest has no effect on them since they're out of scope.

The other thing is, if `counter-reset` is not defined in a given scope, it assumes a value of `0` each time you `counter-increment` or refer to the counter in a `content` rule, which explains why you're getting all `1`s in the first part of the html:

> If 'counter-increment' or 'content' on an element or pseudo-element refers to a counter that is not in the scope of any 'counter-reset', implementations should behave as though a 'counter-reset' had reset the counter to 0 on that element or pseudo-element.

If you have to wrap things in divs, I would:

1. Define a `counter-reset` for the `chapters` counter on `body`, so that it's not assumed 0 each time you use a `counter-increment`.
2. Either nest the `h4`s under their parent `h3`s (which is not cool) or make them siblings to ensure they're in the right scope.

**New HTML:**

```
<div>
    <h3>dddd</h3>
    <h4>dddd</h4>
    <h4>dddd</h4>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>dddd</h3>
    <h4>dddd</h4>
    <h4>dddd</h4>
</div>
```

**Addition to CSS:**

```
body {
    counter-reset: chapter;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/QpG9d/

Comment: I'm wondering, why it still works when I'm only using `counter-increment` but no `counter-reset`? The html is `<h4>a</h4><h4>b</h4><h4>c</h4>`, and the style is `h4{counter-increment:section;} h4:before{content: counter(section);}`

Comment: @Z.H. see the second quote in my answer. The browser behaves as though a `counter-reset: section;` was defined on the first `h4`, because you used `counter-increment` on the `section` counter with no `counter-reset` in scope.

Comment: I have misunderstood your second quote. Now it is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting that the divs are part of the DOM tree now, you either target them as well or you remove them.

```
div {
    counter-increment: chapter;
    counter-reset: section;
}
div:before {
    content: "Chapter " counter(chapter) " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added class to the wrap to differentiate div.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/75MHS/23/)**

HTML

```
<div class="head"><h3>dddd</h3></div>
<div class="sub"><h4>dddd</h4></div>
<div class="sub"><h4>dddd</h4></div>
<div class="head"><h3>dddd</h3></div>
<div class="sub"><h4>dddd</h4></div>
<div class="sub"><h4>dddd</h4></div>
```

CSS

```
div.head {
  counter-increment: chapter;
  counter-reset: section;
}

div.head h3:before {
  content: "Chapter " counter(chapter) " ";
}

div.sub {
  counter-increment: section;
}

div.sub h4:before {
  content: counter(section) " ";
}
```

Comment: this helped me solve my problem, since I had to go with that kind of markup. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that “Counters are ‘self-nesting’, in the sense that resetting a counter in a descendant element or pseudo-element automatically creates a new instance of the counter.” (CSS 2.1, 12.4.1 [Nested counters and scope](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-counter-reset)).

So in the “wrong counter” case, each `div` element containing an `h3` element has its own counter named `chapter`, and each `h3` increments such a local counter.

If you need `div` elements (or `section` elements) for grouping, you can use them this way:

```
<div class=chapter>
<h3>dddd</h3>
<h4>dddd</h4>
<h4>dddd</h4>
</div>
<div class=chapter>
<h3>dddd</h3>
<h4>dddd</h4>
<h4>dddd</h4>
</div>
```

And with such a structure, your CSS would have `.chapter` instead of `h3`:

```
.chapter {
  counter-increment: chapter;
  counter-reset: section;
}
```